# How to setup IIS to verify a client certificate and pass it to the backend as an http header?

Tags: authentication, ssl, iis, client-certificates

I've read quite a few articles on the client certificate authentication in IIS but they mostly talk about the `Required` mode for the client certificate. In this case, the authentication is fully done on the web server side and the user is redirected to the error page in case the certificate is missing or invalid. What I need is to configure IIS to check the client certificate if it exists and pass the results as http headers to my backend. It can be easily done with nginx or apache web servers. The client authentication can be set up as `optional`. Then, the web server checks the certificate and pass the results of the check as `SSL_CLIENT_CERT` (PEM representation of the certificate) and `SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY` (the result of the check - SUCCESS, NONE,...) headers to the application backend. So, on the backend part, I can read the headers and use the values to do the actual authentication -- find a user in the database, issue an auth token. Is it possible in IIS? If yes, is there any documentation on how to bypass the certificate and the check state as http headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a while, I'm writing an answer to my question.

IIS has to be set up with ARR extension to act as a reverse proxy. Then, the client certificate authentication can be enabled for the default web site. Here are several links to instructions how to achieve it:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/06/02/configure-application-request-routing-arr-with-client-certificates/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/01/27/configuring-arr-with-client-certificate/

and couple of links to very solid explanations of the SSL/TLS handshake and certificates in general:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/08/02/ssl-handshake-and-https-bindings-on-iis/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/01/09/self-signed-root-ca-and-intermediate-ca-certificates/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2015/05/27/client-certificate-authentication-part-1/

Basically, the Application Request Routing (ARR) extension should be enabled for the IIS to act as a proxy. Then, you set up proxy bypass routes. Next, you need to set up a valid server certificate for the IIS server and use it in the Default Web Site https bindings. The certificate should be issued by a CA which certificate should be placed into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities and Intermediate Certification Authorities of the Local Computer. Then, you should require SSL in the SSL settings of the Default Web Site with the client certificates setting equal to Accept. In this case, any client that connects to the web server will be asked for a valid client certificate that has been issued by the same CA as the server certificate.

Actually, IIS sends a list of distinguished names of root issuers that are trusted by the web server to the client browser. The browser finds an intersection of this names with client trusted certificate issuers and looks for valid certificates that have been issued by the issuers in the intersection. After that, the user selects one of them (or none) and the selected certificate is checked against the CA certificate. If the certificate passes the check the request is "redirected" to the backend application with the certificate in the `X-ARR-ClientCert` header. The name of the header can be changed in the Server -> Configuration Editor -> system.webServer/proxy -> clientCertHeaderName IIS parameter. In case the user selects (or has) none of the required certificates, the request is "redirected" to the app backend without the header.

Seems, there is no need in the `SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY` header with the state of the check at all. If the certificate is valid it is passed in the header. If the certificate is missing the header is empty. If the certificate is provided by the client but is invalid then the request fails and is not "redirected" to the backend app server at all. Seems, it is a rare case but I have an example.

Imagine, a server certificate is issued by a CA with a distinguished name `XXX`, and there is a client certificate `YYY` (on the client computer) that is issued by a CA with the distinguished name `XXX` but those CAs are not the same (one or both of them are self-signed). In this case, the `YYY` certificate is present in the certificate selection dialog that is shown by a browser but the certificate doesn't pass the further validation against the real web server CA.

That's it. Also, seems IIS has no way to require (or accept) a client certificate for some app endpoints (addresses) only. I haven't found any other option apart from enabling in for the whole web site.

Comment: I have similar issue with client certificate, can u take a look at it and see if its doable or not? https://serverfault.com/questions/900936/iis-arr-reverseproxy-with-client-certificate-authentication-for-backend-iis

Answer (score 0):

IIS ARR can also be configured with a client certificate for the backend or upstream server. In this case users connecting to this IIS do not need to provide the certificate as it will be attached by IIS automatically.

[image: IIS Proxy Configuration]

This configuration is available on IIS server level only.